# Ngrx passing selector result into dumb component

Tags: javascript, angular, ngrx, ngrx-effects

I have a smart component `person` and a dumb child component `person-form`. The `person-form` needs a list of all of the people from the store as well as the current active person. The `person-form` is given the list of people like so:

```
<person-form [people]="people$ | async"></person-form>
```

Now, my question is should I filter out the active person inside the child component using a selector (which feels against the concept of being dumb) or pass in a second parameter for the active person from the selector like so:

```
<person-form [people]="people$ | async" [person]="person$ | async"></person-form>
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I'd say second alternative make way more sense.

Answer (score 2):

if the `person` component knows who is the current person so use the second approach, if you choose the first one you have to filter the list of people wich is bad for you app performance.